# Collapse all groups of certain depth in Google Sheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a google sheet that allows the view of several levels of details. 
The idea is to use the macro feature to use shortcuts that run one macro for each level of detail. Each level of detail shows the active sheet with at a certain depth of groups.
i.e. when I run the macro for the most top level view all row groups are collapsed:

```
function _1stLevelofDetail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().collapseAllRowGroups();
};
```

when I run the macro for the most detailed view (in my case the 4th) all row groups are expanded:

```
function _4thLevelofDetail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().expandAllRowGroups();
};
```

**How can I change the following code so it is robust enough that I can update/add/remove row columns without braking the code**

```
function _3rdLevelofDetail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().expandAllRowGroups();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup(8, 3).collapse();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup(11, 3).collapse();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup(14, 3).collapse();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup(18, 3).collapse();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup(23, 3).collapse();
};
```

*My idea is to get all row groups of depth 3 but I don't know how to put that into code.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem with your code is that Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance

This means that e.g. `spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup(8, 3).collapse();` is being called together with `spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().expandAllRowGroups();` before the former finished executing.

This problem can be solved by implementing [`SpreadsheetApp.flush();`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) after each request that might be a bit time consuming when it is critical that it finishes before the next line of code will be executed.

So, e.g.

```
 spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().expandAllRowGroups();
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup(8, 3).collapse();
```

### UPDATE:

- If you want to dynamically collapse all row groups of a certain depth, you need to retrieve them first.
- For this, you need to use the [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets), which allows you to use the methods of the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) in Apps Script.
- After enabling the Advanced Sheets Service, you can collapse all groups with the desired depth as following:

```
function _3rdLevelofDetail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().expandAllRowGroups();
  var Id = spreadsheet.getId();
  var groups = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(Id, {
    ranges: spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName(),
    fields: "sheets/rowGroups"
  });
  var rowGroups = groups.sheets[0].rowGroups;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowGroups.length; i++){
    if (rowGroups[i].depth == 3){
      var index = rowGroups[i].range.startIndex;
      spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup(index, 3).collapse(); 
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: got that. the initial problem remains though. 
How do I collapse all row groups of group depth 3 for example?

`spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRowGroup([], 3).collapse();`

Comment: You need to retrieve those row groups with the Sheets API first, see my updated answer.

Comment: had to change one part of the code then it does the trick


`var index = rowGroups[i].range.startIndex + 1;`